GCP CDN get "<Error> <Code>NoSuchKey</Code> <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message> </Error>"

I used following script to created the signed URL.
gcloud compute sign-url 
"http://34.49.135.39/bird.jpg" 
--key-name onemorekey 
--key-file onemorekey.key 
--expires-in 10m
And get signed URL e.g. :
http://34.49.135.39/bird.jpg?Expires=1715791268&KeyName=onemorekey&Signature=Kt254sJfM2fu5DJ2-WJK-7kklwQ=
But when I try the signed URL, I keep getting following error.

But you can see, the key is listed.
Any idea?
Thank U!

Find out the cause of it. The way to generate signed url is case sensitive. The file saved in bucket is named as Bird.jpg. But I use bird.jpg to generate the signed URL, which caused the error. But I hope Google can change the error more meaningful, the current error message lead me to a totally wrong direction.
